# Convert Two Longs to a Hex String

Tags: ruby, uuid

I have two longs representing the most and least significant bytes of a UUID respectively. How can I use Ruby to convert these two longs into a 32-character hex representation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [`%` string format operator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-25) like `"%016x"` (sixteen zero padded hex digits):

```
a = 0xCAFEBABECAFEBABE # => 14627333968358193854
b = 0xDEADBEEFDEADBEEF # => 16045690984833335023
'%016x%016x' % [a, b] # => "cafebabecafebabedeadbeefdeadbeef"
```

There are many ways to insert the dashes at the right places if you want to get a properly formatted UUID string; here's the first one that comes to mind:

```
def longs_to_uuid(a, b)
  s = '%016x%016x' % [a, b]
  s.scan(/(.{8})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.{12})/).first.join('-')
end

longs_to_uuid(1,2) # => "00000000-0000-0001-0000-000000000002"
```

Don't forget to consider endianness if that's a concern...

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think endianness does have something to do with it as for some inputs (e.g., 1087192506523562918), I only get back 31 characters.

Comment: @Blumer: check the update to this answer by reloading the page, I included the proper padding needed.